# Upgrading to mongoid 5.0.2: ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to upgrade Mongoid in my Rails app.

My Gemfile now contains:

```
mongoid 5.0.2 (was 4.0.0)
bson 4.0.0 (was 2.3.0)
moped 1.5.3 (was 2.0.2)
mongo 2.2.1
rails 4.2.3
```

According to [the Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#anatomy-of-a-mongoid-config) I have updated `mongoid.yml` to reflect the required changes:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: my_db_name
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
  options:
```

My `application.rb` looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]

    config.generators do |g|
      g.orm :mongoid
    end
  end
end
```

But now, whenever I try to connect with the database I get this stacktrace:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:117:in `>'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:117:in `deserialize'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:107:in `block in read'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:91:in `ensure_connected'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:106:in `read'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:180:in `deliver'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:125:in `block in dispatch'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/monitoring/publishable.rb:47:in `publish_command'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:124:in `dispatch'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:36:in `block in execute'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool.rb:108:in `with_connection'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/server/context.rb:63:in `with_connection'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:34:in `execute'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/database.rb:158:in `command'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:136:in `block in count'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:51:in `call'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:51:in `read_with_retry'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongo-2.2.1/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:135:in `count'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:59:in `block in count'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:488:in `try_cache'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:59:in `count'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:86:in `destroy'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `destroy'
  from (irb):1
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-app/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.1.2
```

Also, when I review the server log, every 30th second or so a new line is added with the text:

```
MONGODB | wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Any idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your ruby version is older than 2.2.1 and judging from mongo-ruby-driver backtrace it might require ruby 2.2.1+.

[Error backtrace](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb#L117)

[Possible culprit, MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE is nil](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb#L73)

Comment: I am running on `ruby 2.1.2p95`, so I will now try to update it. However, I do have another app that runs on `ruby 2.0.0p247` with the new Mongoid/Mongo versions.

Comment: String `freeze` default behaviour might have changed between 2.0 - 2.1 - 2.2, try and see if upgrade works, or try downgrading MONGO gem to 2.2.0. Mongoid requires MONGO >= 2.1 so this should work fine.

Comment: Downgrading to mongo v. 2.1.2 and upgrading Ruby to v. 2.2.2 did the trick. Thanks.